# Looking for a good name for interface with inUse() method

Tags: c#, java

How would you name an interface which provides 1 method inUse()?

Comment: In Java, by changing the word immediately following `interface` to whatever name I wanted.

Comment: Have to disagree with all the `Usable` answers, If I saw the interface `Usable` I would expect a `use()` method, not `inUse()`.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I haven't had expected such an amount of responses. Stackoverflow is really great! You are great! However, I'm going to call my interface IInUse.

Comment: @BlaXpirit a good answer to this question - like Flynn1179's - provide an alternative way of approaching a problem that can be of use to many situations and is, therefore, very helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would actually reconsider the name 'inUse()' in the first place; A boolean value obviously has only two possible values, but you're actually adding the ability to get a state. I'd consider declaring an enum

```
public enum UsageState
{
    Idle,
    InUse
}
```

and name your interface `IHasUsageState`. This gives you the flexibility of adding things like `Starting`, `Finishing`, `WaitingToBeUsed` or other options depending on precisely what is is you're doing, for example if you have threading issues to deal with in the future.

Also, you eliminate the need for negative checks like `if (!obj.InUse()) { }` in favor of the more readable and intuitive `if (obj.Usage == UsageState.Idle) { }`, not to mention you may decide in the future that you might want it to specify WHY it's idle.

Answer (score 9):

`IUsageIndicator` if you want to show that your object **is currently in** use or not.

`IUsable` if you want to show that your object **can** be used or not.

Answer (score 5):

I would name it. `IInUse`. Looks good...

Comment: +1. With that name I clearly understand what this interface mean. (IUsable is good too, but it is more vague)

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer to name it as IUsable keeping in mind the standard conventions that MS follows. (Eg: IEnumerable, IComparable etc)

Comment: Although that your naming convention is absolutely perfect, I think that the member of his interface shows if the object is current in use and not if it can be used (compared - IComparable, enumerated - IEnumerable, etc)

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer
`InUsable`. Sounds everlasting.
 see [here](http://translate.google.com/?hl=de&tab=wT#fr%7Cen%7CinUsable%0A)

Answer (score 2):

I would name it. IUsable. Looks good...

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would have done in Java

```
public interface Usable {

    public boolean inUse();
}
```

Comment: `inUse()` sounds like return type `boolean`

Comment: @oliholz, so true....updated. :)

Answer (score 1):

It should start with Uppercase 'I', so the interface name becomes in your case IInUse.

Follow the C# [coding standards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) over here.

Comment: This counts for C# but not for Java.

Answer (score 0):

How about IExclusiveUseObject?

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for answers for both c# and java?

As a c-sharper, I prefix with "I" and most c# developers I talk to do also, probably because it's in the [microsoft naming conventions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bc1fexb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

However interestingly when search around for java naming conventions I see a mix of prefixed and no prefix.

So in c# perhaps something like:

```
public interface IUsable {

    void InUse();
}
```